# jQuery - event target multiple id selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, dom-events

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test-input, #input').on('change', function(e) {
        var linkElement = $('#the-link');

        // get value user typed in
        var inputFieldValue = e.target.value;

        var input = e.target.value
        // compose route using baseRoute (generated by Laravel)
        var baseRoute = linkElement.data('baseroute');
        // set it as href
        
        linkElement.attr('href', baseRoute + inputFieldValue + input);
        
    });
});
```

I need to get value from these two inputs with id `#test-input` and `#input`, right now it gets me only from last one `#input`.

How can I `e.target` to get both of them? Please help

Comment: I don't see anything that should make it only get the value from `#input`. That's why you use `e.target.value` rather than hard-coding a specific element.

Comment: Why do you need two variables `inputFieldValue` and `input` that refer to the same thing?

Comment: The event only occurs on the specific one that was actually changed. The event has no relationship to the other elements you apply the listener to. Using ID selectors to get each value is likely your best bet

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I just tried with e parameter to attach the both. I need to have a value from both inputs, can I separate this function or made a two and triggered a both at the same time

Comment: There is ONE event fired at a time. So `e.target.value` is the same for both `inputFieldValue` and `input`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I know that, I just tried with this, it's using just the last one ```#input``` So what I need to change to have a values from both inputs?

Comment: @Milos you are describing a scenario that doesn't exist. Either you're describing it poorly, or it isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: So you get `linkElement.attr('href', baseRoute + "A" + "A");` on change of the first input and  `linkElement.attr('href', baseRoute + "B" + "B");` on change of the second.

Comment: Just do `const value1 = $('#test-input').val(), value2 = $('#input').val();` and ignore the event object completely

Comment: Adding to @charlietfl comment: then `linkElement.attr('href', baseRoute + value1 + value2);`

Comment: @charlietfl Please answer my question so I can mark it as correct answer. It's working!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the id selectors to get each value and ignore the event object. The event object knows nothing about the other element. It only references the element the specific change occurred on

```
const value1 = $('#test-input').val(), 
      value2 = $('#input').val();
```